# How can i use the Javascript in adobe Acrobat to run a Python Script?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, pdf, acrobat

I'm bit new to adobe acrobat JavaScript. I was wondering if it is possible to have a click button in the pdf, once i click it, it will run a JavaScript which will run a python code automatically? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

And that is good so, because allowing such things would be extremely unsafe.